# OnRelease when component is replaced in ActivatingHandler

Tags: autofac

I've run into problem when I try to exchange the instance in an `ActivatingHandler` and also use OnRelease. OnRelease expect the concrete type, not the "component type".

Simplified example where both `A` and `A2` implements `IA`...

```
var regBuilder = containerBuilder.RegisterType<A>().As<IA>();
regBuilder.RegistrationData.ActivatingHandlers.Add((sender, e) =>   
{
  e.Instance = new A2();   
}); 
regBuilder.OnRelease(s => ...); //here generic type s is A and not IA -> BAM!
```

How can I run some release code when an component goes out of scope, if it's not the type declared in `RegisterType`?

Answer (score 0):

I found it myself. Under OnActivating [here](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/wiki/Lifetime-Events), there is a simple solution for a similar problem.

First register concrete type. Then register the abstraction/interface based on this concrete type.